# .html() and .alert() show different output

Tags: jquery

I have a jquery that collects the id's of selected spans. 
when i want to display it on html it's coming out without comma, while alert() print for example `1,2,3` html() prints `123`

```
$("#selected_order").click(function() {
        var order = new Array();
        $(".selected").each(function(){
            order.push($(this).attr('data-id'));
        });

        $("#display_selected").html(order);
        alert(order)
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to join the array when outputting to html.

```
$("#display_selected").html(order.join(","));
```

Also initialize your array with `[]` instead of `new Array()`. The latter is useful when you want the array to only have so many values; `new Array(10)`.